# "-webkit-flex" is not a valid value

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a project in VS2015 and I'm trying to use Flex.  I'm getting a syntax error message for this:

```
// Flexbox
.displayFlex() {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.justify-content(@justify: flex-start) {
    -webkit-justify-content: @justify;
    -moz-justify-content: @justify;
    -ms-justify-content: @justify;
    justify-content: @justify;
}
```

It says that: "-webkit-flex" is not a valid value
also I get a syntax error for the -webkit,  -moz and -ms for justify-content.

Can someone tell me are these needed for modern-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me are these needed for modern-browsers

All current browser version do not need the prefix anymore: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex